# How to import and manipulate strings from files

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently working on a project and am stuck on the next step. I am supposed to make the program read multiple columns of data from a file, each with a separate string array. I have managed to make it accept each row individually and print it properly, but I have no clue how to make it read columns to later manipulate. Here is what I have so far;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class HurricaneData {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int line = 1;

    File inputFile = new File("hurcdata2.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(inputFile);
    String hurricane;

    while(inFile.hasNext()){
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            hurricane = inFile.next();
            System.out.print(hurricane + " ");
        } //end for
        System.out.println();
    } //end while

 } //end main

} //end class
```

This gives me; "1980 Aug 945 100 Allen" on one line, "1983 Aug 962 100 Alicia" on the next, and so on. What I'm looking for is a way to read each of the columns into a separate one-dimensional array. I know I could somehow use multidimensional arrays, but the instructions specific limit it to one-dimension. Any and all help is appreciated, even if it's yelling at me and saying how stupid that code is. :) Thank you!!!

Comment: Look into `String`'s `split()` method.

Comment: `String[] columns = hurricane.split(" ");`

Answer (score 0):

You cant read column by column, but if you know how many columns there are per row, you can split the string accordingly, in your case, it looks like `String[] columns = hurricane.split(" ")` will work. It will add each item that has the delimiter in between them(in this case a single space) as a single element in the string array, so "foo bar" will be [foo, bar], make sense?